# Browser differences (Firefox vs Chrome) when using flex-direction, flex-flow

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I noticed an interesting difference between Firefox and Chrome in the following flexbox layout:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tab1 {
  flex: 1 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: orange;
}
.tab2 {
  flex: 1 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: blue;
}
.tab3 {
  flex: 1 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: green;
}
.tab4 {
  flex: 1 0 48%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tab1"></div>
    <div class="tab2"></div>
    <div class="tab3"></div>
    <div class="tab4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run this in Chrome 43, I get horizontal rectangles. However, in Firefox 39 this results in vertical rectangles. The important part is the use of `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` in the element with class `.row`.

In order to get a similar layout, adding `height: 100%;` gives vertical rectangles in Chrome. However, this creates a scrollbar in both browsers due to the (empty) header element. Does anyone know what is the reason of this difference in the layout and what is the best way to fix it?

**UPDATE**:

By the way, I'm interested in understanding why there is a difference in Chrome and Firefox, not so much in obtaining a layout with vertical rectangles. Maybe there is something buggy in the use of `flex-direction: column` or maybe I'm doing something wrong. In any case, it would be helpful to know that.

Comment: Added an update to my answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in `Flex` that causes strange behavior when you don't define `width's` and `height's` also `min-height` is known to cause a lot of problem's.

[Here is a repository](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) of some known issues and how to workaround them.

Side note I believe Safari requires `-webkit-` vendor prefix for `flex` rules

---

Here is a possible workaround give's vertical box's in both FF and Chrome

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tab1 {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: orange;
}
.tab2 {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: blue;
}
.tab3 {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: green;
}
.tab4 {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tab1"></div>
    <div class="tab2"></div>
    <div class="tab3"></div>
    <div class="tab4"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just FYI, this should be a comment right now - when you find the resources and write them up, then convert it to an answer :-)

Comment: That would be great. Thanks. I read about some bugs in Firefox using  `flex-flow` but in this case, Chrome seems to be producing the incorrect behavior. By the way, I was expecting that the initial styles `height: 100%; min-height: 100%;` could be causing some problems.

Comment: Hi Rob I have added the repo for some known issues I didnt find one matching your exact case so ill have a melt around with your code and update.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I wasn't really looking for an alternative way to achieve vertical columns. Instead, I wanted to understand the cause of this difference between browsers using `flex-direction: column;`. Are you sure there is not something atypical in my styles that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Im quite tiered and it's late but im pretty sure its because you where using column instead of row lol also 48% is pretty wide if you where wanting them to site verticly together. if you want something similar to flex but doesnt auto shift and malform elements and keeps columns true column-count could be a better css alternative

Comment: Oh, that's okay. Initially, I changed it to `column` because I wanted to wrap them horizontally as Chrome (incorrectly) does. I also increased their width in order to force the wrapping to take effect. Then I realized that the behavior is different in Firefox and wasn't able to figure out what was happening.